# Updating a SwiftUI Mapbox Map View to Show New Pin Annotations on a Button Press

Tags: ios, swiftui, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I have a SwiftUI project in which I want to forward geocode an address to coordinates and update the Mapbox map view to display a pin annotation at that address's coordinates on a button press.

When pressing the button I created, the action seems to work but the map does not show a new pin anywhere even though my annotation array (which is used for pin placement) is updated with the information for the new address.

My content and map view are as follows:

**MapView**

```
import SwiftUI
import Mapbox



extension MGLPointAnnotation {
    convenience init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.init()
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}



    struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {


    var mapView: MGLMapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL)



       @Binding var annotations: [MGLPointAnnotation]

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MGLMapViewDelegate {
        var control: MapView

        init(_ control: MapView) {
            self.control = control
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {

            return nil
        }


        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MGLMapView {
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }


    func styleURL(_ styleURL: URL) -> MapView {
            mapView.styleURL = styleURL
            return self
        }

        func centerCoordinate(_ centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> MapView {
            mapView.centerCoordinate = centerCoordinate
            return self
        }

        func zoomLevel(_ zoomLevel: Double) -> MapView {
            mapView.zoomLevel = zoomLevel
            return self
        }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
          updateAnnotations()
      }

      func makeCoordinator() -> MapView.Coordinator {
          Coordinator(self)
      }

      private func updateAnnotations() {
          if let currentAnnotations = mapView.annotations {
              mapView.removeAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
          }
          mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
      }

}
```

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI
import Mapbox
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var VModel = ViewModel()

    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

    var userLatitude: CLLocationDegrees {
        return (locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)
     }

     var userLongitude: CLLocationDegrees {
        return (locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)
     }

    var lat: Double {
        return (VModel.lat ?? 0)
    }
    var long: Double {
        return (VModel.lon ?? 0)
    }

    @State var searchedLocation: String = ""
    @State var annotations = [
        MGLPointAnnotation(title: "Mapbox", coordinate: .init(latitude: 37.791434, longitude: -122.396267))
    ]

    var body: some View {

        VStack{

            ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .top)){

                MapView(annotations: $annotations).centerCoordinate(.init(latitude: self.lat, longitude: self.long)).zoomLevel(16).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        self.VModel.fetchCoords(address: "address")


                        let delayInSeconds = 3.0
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayInSeconds) {
                            self.annotations.append(MGLPointAnnotation(title: "Home", coordinate: .init(latitude: self.lat, longitude: self.long)))

                        }

                        print("\(self.annotations)")

                    }, label: {Text("Press to update annotation")})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Any information on updating the map to show new pin annotations on a button press is much appreciated. Please comment if more information is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowledge of your `VModel` to `LocationManager` I stripped them out and just hard-coded some values for some annotations. So although the code below is a much simplified version of yours, you can see the addition of the third annotation when the button is pressed.

It is a straightforward implementation where the view-model (`AnnotationsVM`) controlling the annotations is referenced as an `@ObservedObject` in the `ContextView`. It publishes the array of annotations. These are passed into the `@Binding` variable in the `MapView` and when that array changes (additions, deletions, etc) the updateUIView method updates the map.

```
import SwiftUI
import Mapbox

class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var annos: [MGLPointAnnotation]

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MGLMapView {
        let map = MGLMapView()
        map.styleURL = MGLStyle.outdoorsStyleURL
        map.delegate = context.coordinator

        let location = CLLocation(latitude: 40.763783, longitude: -73.973133)
        map.setCenter(location.coordinate, zoomLevel: 13, animated: true)

        return map
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: Context) {
        if let currentAnnotations = uiView.annotations {
            uiView.removeAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
        }
        uiView.addAnnotations(annos)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
        return MapViewCoordinator()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var annotationsVM = AnnotationsVM()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MapView(annos: $annotationsVM.annos)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Hello"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    self.annotationsVM.addNextAnnotation()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                }))
        }

    }
}

class AnnotationsVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var annos = [MGLPointAnnotation]()

    init() {
        var annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "Apple Store"
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.77, longitude: -73.98)
        annotation.subtitle = "Think Different"
        annos.append(annotation)

        annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "Shoe Store"
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.78, longitude: -73.98)
        annotation.subtitle = "Shoe Different"
        annos.append(annotation)
    }

    func addNextAnnotation() {
        let newAnnotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        newAnnotation.title = "New Annotation"
        newAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.763783, longitude: -73.973133)
        newAnnotation.subtitle = "Ben Button"
        annos.append(newAnnotation)
    }
}
```